# Google cloud translate API - "Daily Limit Exceeded"

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gcloud

I'm writing a bit of python using the google cloud api to translate some text.

I have set up billing on my account and it says it's active (with some credit added for the free trial). I created an application_default_credentials.json file with -

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

Which asked me to log in to my account (I logged into the same account I set billing up on).

I then used -

```
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "/home/theo/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json"
```

at the start of my python script. For the coding I followed these samples here - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/translate/cloud-client

Yesterday the api wouldn't work and I would receive "daily limit exceeded" even though I had not used it yet. Eventually I gave up and decided to sleep on it.

Tried again today and it was working. Without having to do anything. Ah great I thought, it must just have taken a while to update my billing information.

But I've since translated a few things, maybe 10000 characters and I'm already receiving the same error message.

I did create a "Project" on the cloud console and have an api key from there. I'm not entirely sure how to use it because the documentation I linked above just uses the json credentials file. From what I've read online, using the json file is recommended over using a key now.

Any ideas about what I need to do?

Thanks.

Comment: Also check that you have a daily billing limit set for your project.

Comment: I can't see any option to do that. The weird thing is that I look up usage quotas, and the translation api says 0 characters used. This makes me think I'm somehow not connecting to the right api or account.

Comment: In the developer console go to `App Engine` -> `Settings` -> `Application Settings` then `Edit` and `Daily spending`. I just noticed the ability to also set alerts, in `Billing` -> `Budgets & alerts`, but I didn't play with this one yet.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by creating a token at https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/serviceaccountkey instead of the one created with the gcloud auth command.

After I referenced the generated json file from that page it started working.

More info here - https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started